# I'm trying to display search results for both name and genres for particular TV shows in React, how to use one filter method for both name and genre?

Tags: reactjs

***My table.js file below. I've managed to search and filter through my table in order to display search results for show by name, but not sure how to implement a second condition so that the same search bar can be used to display searches for shows by genre.***

Genres is an array, like so: `genres: ["Drama", "Action", "Adventure"]`

As I said previously, I'm able to filter through shows using the user input to find shows by name, but I'd like to use that same filter function to also display results by genre. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

```
export default class Table extends Component {
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  this.state = {
    searchByTitle: ""
  };
  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
}

handleChange(event) {
  this.setState({searchByTitle : event.target.value})
}

  renderRow(show) {
    return (
      <tr key={show.id}>
        <td className="border border-green-600">
          {show.image && (
            <img className="w-full" src={show.image.medium} alt={show.name} />
          )}
        </td>
        <td className="border border-green-600 bg-green-100">{show.name}</td>
        <td className="border border-green-600 bg-green-100">
          {show.genres.join(", ")}
        </td>
        <td className="border border-green-600 bg-green-100">{show.runtime}</td>
        <td className="border border-green-600 bg-green-100">
          {show.network && show.network.name}
        </td>
        <td className="border border-green-600 bg-green-100">{show.status}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  }

  render() {

    const filterShows = (shows, query) => {
      if (!query) {
        return shows;
      }

      return shows.filter((show) => {
        const showName = show.name.toLowerCase();
        // const showGenres = show.genres.join(", ")
        return showName.includes(query)
      })
    }

    const filteredShows = filterShows(this.props.shows, this.state.searchByTitle)

    return (
        <table className="table-fixed border-collapse">
          <thead>
            <tr> 
              <input
                  type="text"
                  id="header-search"
                  placeholder="Search shows"
                  name="search"
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
            </tr>
              <tr>
                <th className="w-1/12">Poster</th>
                <th className="w-4/12">Name</th>
                <th className="w-4/12">Genres</th>
                <th className="w-1/12">Runtime</th>
                <th className="w-1/12">Network</th>
                <th className="w-1/12">Status</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>{filteredShows.map((show) => this.renderRow(show))}</tbody>
        </table>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Nevermind, I got it! Thank you to anyone who tried to help.**

Just had change up my filterShows function so that it joined the array and then used toLowerCase(). See below:

```
const filterShows = (shows, query) => {
      if (!query) {
        return shows;
      }

      return shows.filter((show) => {
        const showName = show.name.toLowerCase();
        const showGenres = show.genres.join(", ").toLowerCase();
        // const showGenre = show.genres;
        return showName.includes(query) || showGenres.includes(query);
      });
    };
```